# Odoo 10.0 - Don't round quantity

Tags: odoo-10

I'm using Odoo 10.0 Community Edition and I can't find where to configure to specify Odoo to do not round the quantity ordered.

For example, if the unit of an article is days, I would like to be able to set 1.5 days. But every time I try, Odoo automatically round the value to 2 (or to 1 if I put 1.4 days). I've tried on different products with different unit (days, hours, unit, etc.) but same result.

Could you please tell me where to configure this ?

Thanks

Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

That was simple but not obvious change the decimal accuracy for the Product Unit of Measure (dev mode needs to be activate) :
Settings > Technical > Database Structure > Decimal Accuracy >  Product Unit of Measure > decimal precision > Set the number you want (for example 1 if you want 1 decimal)